# Calculate diff in days between events for 1,000 columns

Tags: rstudio, data-science

I'm trying to test where my real world data falls on a hypothetical probability distribution. I have created a DF of 1000 random Var and recoded it to match the probability of my real world events.

Next I want to calculate the "time between Events" (IE, the time between each 1 occurring), Then store the mean time between events for each random variable, so I can plot it. (End goal is 1 variable of 1000 means)

The code below I have created the random variables, recoded them, and added a date range.

```
dat <-as.data.frame( matrix (0, nr=1303, nc = 1000))
for (i in 1:1000){x<- runif(1303)
dat[,i] <-x}
#calculating values to 0,1.
dat[,] <- ifelse(dat[,] < "0.01611665", 1, ifelse(dat[,] > "0.01611665", 0, 1 ))
#creating date range
start_date <- as.Date("2016/10/10")
Date<- seq(start_date, by = "day", length.out = 1303)
#add date vector to a df
dat$date <- Date
```

I'm not sure how to calculate the time between events for all variables. I have done it for my real world data (only 21 events in 1303 days) in the code below, but I'm not sure how to scale it to apply to all 1000 random variables, or how to extract 1000 mean "time between events" to a separate df.

```
 events <- sort(sample(never1$date1, 21))
    d <- c(NA, diff(events))
```

I know my solution involves lubridate and dplyr and rolling calculations. But my googleFU isn't helping too much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

```
dat <- as.data.frame( matrix(0, nr=1303, nc = 1000) )

  #Generate random numbers
  for (i in 1:1000){
    x<- runif(1303) 
    dat[,i] <-x
  }


  #Split random numbers into zero and ones at the desired prevalence
  dat[,] <- ifelse(dat[,] < "0.01611665", 1, ifelse(dat[,] > "0.01611665", 0, 1 ) )

  length(dat[,1])

  plot.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nr = 1000, nc = 3))
  colnames(plot.df) <- c("Mean","Sd","Median")

  #Check the run length encoding
  for (i in 1:1000){
  runs <- rle(dat[,i])
  #Check the length of runs
  runs$lengths
  #Remove the incident days and leave the length of 'no incident' runs
  noinc.days   <- runs$lengths[which(runs$lengths > 1)]
  plot.df[i,1] <- mean(noinc.days)
  plot.df[i,2] <- sd(noinc.days)
  plot.df[i,3] <- median(noinc.days)
```

Followed by the appropriate GGplots.